# Why the same query has different entries on pg_stat_statements

Tags: postgresql

So this query

```
SELECT "settings"."tier_code", "settings"."tier_id", "settings"."property_name",
       "settings"."property_value", "settings"."created_at", "settings"."updated_at",
       "settings"."modified_by_app_user_id" FROM "settings"
WHERE (("settings"."tier_code" = $5 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $1)
    OR ("settings"."tier_code" = $6 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $2)
    OR ("settings"."tier_code" = $7 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $3)
    OR ("settings"."tier_code" = $8 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $4))
ORDER BY CASE
     WHEN tier_code = $9 THEN $10
     WHEN tier_code = $11 THEN $12
     WHEN tier_code = $13 THEN $14
     WHEN tier_code = $15 THEN $16
     END
```

Appears on different entries on `pg_stat_statements` with different stats. According to [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgstatstatements.html):

> In some cases, queries with visibly different texts might get merged into a single pg_stat_statements entry. Normally this will happen only for semantically equivalent queries, but there is a small chance of hash collisions causing unrelated queries to be merged into one entry. (This cannot happen for queries belonging to different users or databases, however.)

> Since the queryid hash value is computed on the post-parse-analysis representation of the queries, the opposite is also possible: queries with identical texts might appear as separate entries, if they have different meanings as a result of factors such as different search_path settings.

But the thing is the two entries are coming from exactly the same backend with the same connection parameters. Does someone know who to identify why those two entries are not stored on the same entry?

### EDIT 1

Adding `pg_stat_statements` entries showing the repeated entries.

```
|userid|dbid  |queryid   |query                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |calls  |total_time       |min_time|max_time  |mean_time          |stddev_time        |rows     |shared_blks_hit|shared_blks_read|shared_blks_dirtied|shared_blks_written|local_blks_hit|local_blks_read|local_blks_dirtied|local_blks_written|temp_blks_read|temp_blks_written|blk_read_time|blk_write_time|
|------|------|----------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------|-----------------|--------|----------|-------------------|-------------------|---------|---------------|----------------|-------------------|-------------------|--------------|---------------|------------------|------------------|--------------|-----------------|-------------|--------------|
|190355|190354|1169328217|SELECT "settings"."tier_code", "settings"."tier_id", "settings"."property_name",¶       "settings"."property_value", "settings"."created_at", "settings"."updated_at",¶       "settings"."modified_by_app_user_id" FROM "settings"¶WHERE (("settings"."tier_code" = $5 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $1)¶    OR ("settings"."tier_code" = $6 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $2)¶    OR ("settings"."tier_code" = $7 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $3)¶    OR ("settings"."tier_code" = $8 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $4))¶ORDER BY CASE¶     WHEN tier_code = $9 THEN $10¶     WHEN tier_code = $11 THEN $12¶     WHEN tier_code = $13 THEN $14¶     WHEN tier_code = $15 THEN $16¶     END|6997474|531415.2983119462|0.018083|139.059538|0.07594387607756962|0.23361057550853626|151907150|52843544       |1664            |0                  |0                  |0             |0              |0                 |0                 |0             |0                |0.0          |0.0           |
|190355|190354|1445417828|SELECT "settings"."tier_code", "settings"."tier_id", "settings"."property_name",¶       "settings"."property_value", "settings"."created_at", "settings"."updated_at",¶       "settings"."modified_by_app_user_id" FROM "settings"¶WHERE (("settings"."tier_code" = $5 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $1)¶    OR ("settings"."tier_code" = $6 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $2)¶    OR ("settings"."tier_code" = $7 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $3)¶    OR ("settings"."tier_code" = $8 AND "settings"."tier_id" = $4))¶ORDER BY CASE¶     WHEN tier_code = $9 THEN $10¶     WHEN tier_code = $11 THEN $12¶     WHEN tier_code = $13 THEN $14¶     WHEN tier_code = $15 THEN $16¶     END|3964032|529211.9708209931|0.034516|92.213045 |0.13350345577962192|0.34657615221428545|142187678|69095391       |13134           |0                  |0                  |0             |0              |0                 |0                 |0             |0                |0.0          |0.0           |
```

Comment: Please quote the results from a `pg_stat_statements` query with all columns showing the same entry twice.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz Albe for your answer. I have added the data you requested. Let me know if is enough.

Comment: Thanks. I have no explanation. Perhaps whitespace or newline differences.

Comment: I have noticed the same exact thing, still no one could answer, did you ever find why? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75531005/pg-stat-statements-same-query-different-queryid